# How to autocomplete a file or directory name in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete, bash-completion

For example, there are three files(or directories) here.

```
FooGood FooBad FooUnknown
```

I wonder if there's a way to autocomplete with the keyword of the filenames.

Such as: `vim Good<TAB>` => `vim FooGood`

or `vim Bad<TAB>` => `vim FooBad`.

--

Thanks in advance for your answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

This type of autocomplete is fuzzy complete.

https://superuser.com/questions/561451/is-there-a-shell-which-supports-fuzzy-completion-as-in-sublime-text

https://github.com/mgalgs/fuzzy_bash_completion

Comment: thanks for your answer. but it doesn't work for me. see here: https://github.com/mgalgs/fuzzy_bash_completion/issues/7. Maybe i use a too old version of bash. :(

Comment: I have tested and worked. after adding lines according to the instrument. run `fuzzy_setup_for_command cd` in new window and it will enabled for `cd` command

Answer (score -1):

for smooth auto completion you should have a look at [ZSH shell](http://www.zsh.org/).If you like ZSH shell then also install [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).It offers plugins and themes and notifies users of updates.